# RTCQuicTransport: The provided value cannot be converted to a sequence

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, chromium, quic

When I try to call the constructor of RTCQuicTransport on Javascript it throws the error: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'RTCQuicTransport': The provided value cannot be converted to a sequence.

Assumming the Constructor needs two parameters, a RTCIceTransport object and one certificate generated with RTCPeerConnection.generateCertificate(), It should work in this way but no.

I've tried passing 'null' as certificate, but still throwing same error message. If I just pass the RTCIceTransport object, it throw that the construct needs two parameters.

```
// Include some helper functions
//import {trace, errorHandler, mySendLocalCandidate, 
myIceGathererStateChange,
//  myIceTransportStateChange, myDtlsTransportStateChange} from 'helper';
//import 'helper.js';

function initiate(mySignaller) {
// Prepare the IceGatherer
var gatherOptions = {
  gatherPolicy: "all",
  iceServers: [
    { urls: "stun:stun1.example.net" },
    { urls: "turn:turn.example.org", username: "user", credential: 
    "myPassword",
      credentialType: "password" }
   ]
};

// Create the IceTransport
var ice = new RTCIceTransport();
ice.onstatechange = function(event) {
  myIceGathererStateChange("iceGatherer", event.state);
};
// Handle errors
// Prepare to signal local candidates
ice.onlocalcandidate = function(event) {
  mySignaller.mySendLocalCandidate(event.candidate);
};

// Start gathering
ice.gather(gatherOptions);

// Prepare to handle remote ICE candidates
console.log(ice);
mySignaller.onRemoteCandidate = function(remote) {
  ice.addRemoteCandidate(remote.candidate);
};

// Create the certificate
var certs = {};
var keygenAlgorithm = { name: "ECDSA", namedCurve: "P-256"};

RTCPeerConnection.generateCertificate(keygenAlgorithm).
then(function(certificate){
  certs[0] = certificate;
}, function(){
  trace('Certificate could not be created');
});
// Create the DtlsTransport and QuicTransport
var quic = new RTCQuicTransport(ice, certs[0]);
console.log(quic);
mySignaller.sendInitiate({
  ice: iceGatherer.getLocalParameters(),
  quic: quic.getLocalParameters(),
  // ... marshall RtpSender/RtpReceiver capabilities as in Section 6.6 
Examples 8 and 9.
}, function(remote) {
  // Start the IceTransport, DtlsTransport and QuicTransport
  ice.start(iceGatherer, remote.ice, RTCIceRole.controlling);
  dtls.start(remote.dtls);
  quic.start(remote.quic);
  // ... configure RtpSender/RtpReceiver objects as in Section 6.6 
Examples 8 and 9.
});}
```

I'm following the ORTC quic example, and I expect to obtain an RTCQuicTransport object.

Thanks in advance

**Edit**:

I've realized that when I print my certificate inside the generateCertificate() function, It works properly:

```
RTCCertificate {expires: 1552505428000}
expires: 1552505428000
```

But, out of that function, I get this:

```
console.log(certs);
```

Result:

```
{}
  [0] RTCCertificate
      expires: 1552505951000
```

Then I try:

```
console.log(certs[0]);
```

Result:

```
undefined
```

Comment: Make sure you show the exact and full errors and traces as searchable, copyable, formatted text (via an [edit]).

Comment: Are you trying the Chrome experiment described in https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/01/rtcquictransport-api ? Unfortunately the experiment doesn't follow the spec. https://webrtchacks.com/first-steps-with-quic-datachannel/ has another description as well as running code.

Comment: Thanks for the recomendation, @jdv

Comment: Phillipp, Hi. I've tried the sample code in the ORTC API spec: https://draft.ortc.org/#rtcquicexample*
This code does not run because only Edge browser have support for RTCIceGatherer, However, I modified the code to obtain my RTCIceTransport object wich is needed for RTCQuicTransport.
I tried the api that you cited "developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/01/rtcquictransport-api", but since RTCQuicTransport object is created from 2 parameters (IceTransport object, certs), That code does not work.
Thanks for the second reference, I'll take a look and try it

Comment: Edge doesn't support QUICTransport sadly.

Comment: Thank you @PhilippHancke I seriously was thinking in implement this on Edge, is good to know that.

Comment: I still having this error message:
[link] Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'RTCQuicTransport': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.
In this line:
`const quic1 = new RTCQuicTransport(ice1);`

Comment: does window.RTCQuicTransport exist even? It should not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web browser compatible with RTCIceTransport and RTCQuic transport is Chrome in version 73 Beta, according this: [RTCQuicTransport over chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/01/rtcquictransport-api)
Although I was trying to run it in chrome 72 with `--enable-blink-features=RTCQuicTransport,RTCIceTransportExtension` flag, it was not enough.

In chrome 73 beta I could create an RTCQuicTransport by passing `null` as second parameter and also generating my own certificate.